# How can I procceed when a question is deleted with an invalid criteria?

Tags: discussion, support, close-reasons

Sorry for asking that but it's the first time that happens to me and I'm interested on giving the right steps following the site rules.

I have asked [something](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/113875/real-value-of-ads-app-conversion-rates-google-facebook) about how the inner working of a concrete aspect of a Google Adwords app campaign, and a Facebook Ads app campaign. Obviously the answer can be X for Google and Y for Facebook, they are totally independant advertising platforms, I just posted that together because the question was the same for both and I thought it would be interesting to discuss that on the same post, gathering the answer to one and the other platform.

The question was closed and I was encouraged to post it on another StackExchange site (here) and ask separately for Google and Facebook, since the answers would have nothing to do one with the other. I did so: [1](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/112186/real-value-of-google-ads-app-conversion-rates), [2](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/112187/real-value-of-facebook-ads-app-conversion-rates).

Both questions were put on hold since "they were asking nearly the same". I exposed my thoughts and finally the Google one was reactivated, but the Facebook one was closed with a comment "You can extrapolate any answers you get their to apply to Facebook as well", which IMHO and with all my respects, has no sense.

What should I do to get my Facebook question posted?

Lots of thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand your question about Facebook well enough.   It is clear that you are asking about Facebook advertising.   I'm not sure exactly what your question is though.   Are you asking if Facebook charges your when the user clicks on the ad vs when they install an app?

Comment: It also sounds like your question is about promoting your mobile app and not about promoting your website.   Questions about online advertising are only on-topic on Pro Webmasters when they relate to your website.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller no, I am asking if the "this add achieved 4 installs" will be real, or just an estimation. I wonder if facebook can know in any way that the user who clicked the add then really installed the app. I know you have an add click metrics and an app start metrics, but are they able to precisely join both data?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller given that, do you think my question can be improved for better understanding? I don't eimagine how to explain it in other way :/

Comment: @StephenOstermiller do you know which is the right place then? I was sent here from webapps.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Merge the 2 questions and forget about describing a specific app (so instead of say "blah blah" you use "if I have an app...")